# Why does importing JFrame require inheritance but FlowLayout, JLabel, etc not?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, flowlayout

I just started learning about GUIs and was watching a tutorial from "thenewboston" where he wrote this. But I don't understand why JFrame is the only import that's inherited? I'm not sure if this is just one of those cases where it has be because java would give it an error otherwise.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class tuna extends JFrame {

    private JLabel item1;

    public tuna(){
        super("The title bar");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());            
        item1 = new JLabel("This is a sentence.");
        item1.setToolTipText("This is gonna show up on hover");
        add(item1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to learn more basic Java before you start learning GUI. This question is about basic usage of classes.

Answer (score 2):

JFrame does NOT require inheritance. In fact you should NOT use inheritance.

Look at the `FrameDemo.java` code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for a better design.

Also, Java class names should start with an upper case character. I would stick with the Swing tutorials instead of the current tutorials you are looking at.